# Can anyone help explain this answer to a problem about intrest and payments?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I dont understand how the solution is obtained..I try to use present value of an annuity immediate but I dont see how to get the answer

[image]
The answer is,

[image]

Can we just use the intrest given? since the payment period and intrest conversion align? What does it mean by a nominal annual rate compounded every half month, isnt that ussually given with a superscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $24$ half-months in a year, so the interest every half-month is $\frac 6{24}\%=\frac 14\%$.  You can use your usual formula with that or make a spreadsheet showing the interest, payment, and balance every half-month.  Interest is often quoted as a nominal annual amount which must be scaled to the payment period.

Alternately, nothing in the problem statement prohibits saying $n=1$ and the only payment is $(1+0.0025) \cdot 2,000,000=2,005,000$, which is duly no less than $20,000$

Comment: Thanks, so is it the same as what I would used to be seeing, $i^{(24)}$?

Comment: I vaguely remember that symbol, but am not familiar with it.